# Is overriding core code the same as overriding templates and layout files?

Tags: magento, magento2

Can anyone advise on how to override the core code?
Specifically this file:
vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/SearchResultApplier.php
I've overridden templates and layout files in my custom theme, but don't know how to do the same for code files.
It's more the file structure I'm looking for I guess, but I also feel that overriding the code files is a bit more in depth.
Appreciate and help.
Thank you
Andy

I've tried mimicking the template, layout files but this method didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use di.xml for overriding any class and methods:
Please check below magento standard:

```
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/build/dependency-injection-file/#override-a-method-using-preference-nodes
```